# DataTable dynamic computed column

Tags: c#, datatable, calculated-columns

I need a way to update a calculated Datatable's Column base on string in other string column.
for example:

```
x          y         FormulaCol         ComputedCol
------------------------------          -----------
2          5         x+y                7
2          5         x*y                10
```

i know that i can use a for loop and calculate result column:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < DT.Rows.Count; i++){
string formula=DT.Rows[i]["FormulaCol"].ToString().Replace("x",DT.Rows[i]["x"]).Replace("y",DT.Rows[i]["y"])
DT.Rows[i]["ComputedCol"] =(int)DT.Compute(formula , "")
  }
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: In what way better?

Comment: auto computed way without for loop or a way with for loop without replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use loop, try this...

```
DT = DT.AsEnumerable()
       .Select(
                row =>
                { 
                  row["ComputedCol"] = (int)DT.Compute(row["FormulaCol"].ToString()
                             .Replace("x", row["x"].ToString())
                             .Replace("y", row["y"].ToString()), "");
                  return row;
                 }
               ).CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple but long solution:
This is how your table will look like,

```
x          y         FormulaCol         ComputedCol
------------------------------          -----------
2          5         +                7
2          5         *                10
```

and your **code**:

```
for (int i = 0; i < DT.Rows.Count; i++){
     switch(DT.Rows[i]["FormulaCol"].ToString()){
         case "+":
             int formula=(int) DT.Rows[i]["x"] + (int) DT.Rows[i]["y"];
             DT.Rows[i]["ComputedCol"] = formula;
             break;
         case "-":
             int formula=(int) DT.Rows[i]["x"] - (int) DT.Rows[i]["y"];
             DT.Rows[i]["ComputedCol"] = formula;
             break;
         case "*":
             int formula=(int) DT.Rows[i]["x"] * (int) DT.Rows[i]["y"];
             DT.Rows[i]["ComputedCol"] = formula;
             break;
         case "/":
             int formula=(int) DT.Rows[i]["x"] / (int) DT.Rows[i]["y"];
             DT.Rows[i]["ComputedCol"] = formula;
             break;
     }
 }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I use x+y only for sample, i wanted to have formula column that user can enter expression .

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < DT.Rows.Count; i++){

string formula=DT.Rows[i]["FormulaCol"].ToString()
 for (int j = 0; j < DT.Columns.Count; j++){

 furmula=formula.Replace(DT.Columns[j].Name ,DT.Rows[i][j].ToString())

 }

DT.Rows[i]["ComputedCol"] =(int)DT.Compute(formula , "")
}
```